# 'mongod wiredTiger' on Ubuntu?

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I cannot use `wiredTiger` as a service for `MongoDB`.

I followed this step by step guide;
 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/

Step-1: Start 3.0 mongod.OK, I did.
Step-2: Export the data using mongodump. OK 
Step-3: Create data directory for WiredTiger. OK - user permissions were adjusted.
Step-4: Restart the mongod with WiredTiger. OK

`mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath <newWiredTigerDBPath>`
And yes, `mongod` worked. But the `Step-5` says that "Upload the exported data using mongorestore." However my console remains busy and says "waiting for connections on port 27017" because the last command does not include a service like `service mongod start`.

Then I tried editing my `/etc/mongod.conf` file to run as a service. But I couldn't. I added wiredTiger directory as dbpath but I guess I need to edit `/etc/init/mongod.conf` file because it contains some codes that change the permissions of the db directory.

After spending 8 hours, I don't think there's sufficient documentation to help,
 so I'd like to ask;
What should I do in order to be able to use wiredTiger with MongoDB?
I'm wondering if there's anybody who has managed to achieve this?

**console**
[image]

**Edit on 2015-04-01:**
I tried [change-storage-engine-to-wiredtiger](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/#change-storage-engine-to-wiredtiger) section that is on the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to use wiredTiger upgrading MongoDB. However, at `May 17` I uninstalled MongoDB 2.6 then installed MongoDB 3.0.3 . Immediate after the installation, I added `storageEngine=wiredTiger` on top of my mongod.conf file. Then I gave `sudo service mongod start` command and eventually I could.

---

**Edit:**

For fresh installed as directed by [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/);

1. Open configuration file using `sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf`
2. Change the `#  engine` line to `engine: wiredTiger` like the below
3. Run mongod using the command `sudo service mongod start`

.

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
  engine: wiredTiger
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:
```

---

**Edit:**

If the current version is supported the wiredTiger;

1. Get the backup of the current database using [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) command
2. Stop the mongod service using `sudo service mongod stop` command
3. Add `storageEngine=wiredTiger` text as the first line of `mongod.conf` file
4. Delete the all file on `/var/lib/mongodb` (or `/data/db` folder if used)
   [This is important. Because MongoDB cannot convert the current MMAP db files to wiredTiger format]
5. Start the mongod service using `sudo service mongod start` command
6. Restore the database from the backup using [mongorestore][2] command
7. wiredTiger is being used...

Comment: For Immediate after the installation, I added storageEngine=wiredTiger on top of my mongod.conf file. Then I gave sudo service mongod start command and eventually I could. +1

Answer (score 1):

Steps for migrating 2.6 to 3.0 on Ubuntu and using the new WiredTiger storage engine:

1. Backup current database:

   `mongodump --out final_2.6_backup`
2. Stop mongodb service:

   `service mongodb stop`
3. Remove current database files:

   `rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/*`
4. Edit /etc/mongod.conf to use the new storage engine:

   `storageEngine=wiredTiger`
5. Start mongodb:

   `service mongodb start`
6. Restore database:

   `mongorestore final_2.6_backup`

Answer (score 0):

I use wiredTiger in a sharded cluster. I find it easier to roll a hidden node into each replica set and then swap the 4th node with a secondary.

I then: 
1. stop the MongoDB service on the now 4th node
2. restart the instance, as a service, pointed to the new dbpath for and the storageengine option set to wiredTiger.
3. wait for the node to synch.
4. drop the old dbpath

I repeat that step until all nodes are up to date.

- If you are not using a replica set, it does appear you are limited to using mongodump and mongorestore. We have way too much data to rely on those tools. They take too long to execute.

Comment: Thanks Dillon, I don't have any replica set. Yes you're right `mongorestore` take a bit long time to execute.